# How to cancel all click events in document in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, click

How can I cancel all click events in a HTML document?

I have a Webapp where a situation can occur where the user needs to accept a message before to go on.
The idea is that the message appears and when the user clicks somewhere else the message blinks or tries to catch the user's attention

This app is intended to be used by administrations using IE 8 and up + modern browsers, that's why I was hoping for a jquery solution.

At the moment, I tried:

## failed solution 1

```
$(document).bind('click', function(event){
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('.alertbox').effect('shake');
            return false;
        });
```

hoping the return false  or the event stop propagation would stop the click, But I found out the event bubbles up from the Dom element to the document, so the dom element fires the click anyway.

## failed solution 2

I found a solution in pure JS:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

using true as a third argument will bind the listener to the capture phase and execute the function before anything else gets executed, but this doesn't work well in IE.

## failed solution 3

Using a div covering the whole document, this could be a solution for other people, but not in this precise scenario, because the error message (needs to be clickable) sits in a complex structure (everything is moving and css keeps everything in place).
Moving this element on top of the covering div to make it the only clickable solution is a nice solution, but not in this case..

I don't necessarily need a solution to get a pre-bubble click event in IE (although this would be nice) If I could find a trick or a workaround, I could live with it. Any idea?

## working solution 3

I ended up using the failed solution 3 and added a fake hit zone representing the message's boundaries.
I don't verify the right boundary because messages are always touching the right side of the browser's window.

```
$('#screencurtain').click(function(event)
{  
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if(event.clientX > $('#messages').offset().left  &&  event.clientY > $('#messages').offset().top && event.clientY < $('#messages').offset().top + $('#messages').height())
    {
        $('#screencurtain').hide();
        $('#messages').click();
    }
    else
    {
        $('.alertbox').effect('pulsate');
    }
});
```

Comment: Place a transparent element over the entire document.

Comment: But then how can I detect the user click on the message? Clicking on the message is what makes this situation resolve and make the app usable again.

Comment: Place the message in an element that sits on top of the transparent element. A good example of this is the jQuery UI Dialog using `modal: true`.

Comment: @KevinB is right. This is solved using a layer over the rest of the document. Very common everywhere. The message will be over the layer so you would be able to detect clicks over it.

Comment: This is correct in the question's context, however the message sits inside a css structure and cannot sit on top of the other ones.. sorry :) it's position is needed in the layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place a transparent div covering the entire screen

```
var screenWidth = $(window).width(), screenHeight = $(window).height();

$("<div>").width(screenWidth).height(screenHeight).css({ 
    zIndex : 100000
}).appendTo("body");

//Disables scrolling if exists
$("html, body").css({ 'overflow' : '100%', 'height' : '100%' });
```

Comment: that's the idea behind the questions comments, but I cannot move the clickable div on top of this new one.

Comment: @VincentDuprez You could temporarily move the message `div` on top, then return it back to its original position, when user leaves the message.

Comment: Just increase the clickable div's z-index property to 100001. In that way the clickable div will be on top of the transparent div

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you more:-

```
$(function() {

$('div').click(function() {
   alert('div1'); 
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    alert('document');
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);

$('div').click(function() {
   alert('div2'); 
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wLwMh/381/

Comment: @VincentDuprez You just need to modify it slightly to make it work using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at .off() http://api.jquery.com/off/

if you have something with a click event like this:

```
$("#selector").on('click', function(){
    //do something here
});
```

at any point you can do this and remove the click handler:

```
$("#selector").off('click');
```

or to remove all events from the selector e.g click mouseenter, mouseleave, hover etc just leave .off blank like this:

```
$("#selector").off();
```

This way you can remove click events from certain elements then re-enable them when needed.

Comment: For completeness: `$('*').off('click')` will unbind it from all elements if you're not sure which elements have events bounded. May be quite slow in large DOMs though, so use at your own risk.

Comment: @RenéWolferink That won't handle links being clicked.  You actually need to do the opposite, and capture click events for everything and the use `preventDefault()` to stop anything happening :)

Comment: Exactly as Archer said, I will ude the off method once the blocade will be removed, to remove the document click handler. (if I use a document click handler...)

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it with your 1st attempt.  Try this...

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.alertbox').effect('shake');
});
```

The real problem comes when you want to then be able to click things again.

Comment: interesting, I'll try it out

Comment: Sorry, other elements click actions are still triggered.